# How to keep navigation menu state between page navigations and refresh

Tags: laravel, routes, accordion

Im using laravel to develop a website. There is a side panel for navigating between the different pages of the website. Some pages are grouped together in an accordion (or dropdown). When I click on one of the options within the accordion it navigates to the page but the accordion closes immediately. How do I keep it open??

here is how the accordion is

```
<li class="treeview">
            <a href="#">
                <span>Group of pages</span>
            <ul class="treeview-menu"
                style="display: none;">
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ route('a-route') }}">Page 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ route('a-second-route') }}">Page 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
</li>
```

Any help is appreciated.

ps. It might be worth it to add that I am using [AdminLTE](https://almsaeedstudio.com/) as a template.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add `Active` class in `li`

```
<li class="treeview {{ ((Request::is('a-page')) || (Request::is('a-second-page')) ? 'active' : '') }}">
    <a href="#">
        <span>Group of pages</span>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li class="{{ ((Request::is('a-page')) ? 'active' : '') }}">
                <a href="{{ url('a-page') }}">Page 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="{{ ((Request::is('a-second-page')) ? 'active' : '') }}">
                <a href="{{ url('a-second-page') }}">Page 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

OR

```
<li class="treeview {{ ((Route::currentRouteName() == 'a-route') || (Route::currentRouteName() == 'a-second-route') ? 'active' : '') }}">
    <a href="#">
        <span>Group of pages</span>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li class="{{ ((Route::currentRouteName() == 'a-route') ? 'active' : '') }}">
                <a href="{{ route('a-route') }}">Page 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="{{ ((Route::currentRouteName() == 'a-second-route') ? 'active' : '') }}">
                <a href="{{ route('a-second-route') }}">Page 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</li>
```